# How do I "connect" one wireless network interface to anothet

Tags: local-area-network, wds, wlan

Basically I have two dd wrt routers(TP-LINK and ASUS) working in "LAN-WAN" infrastructure(so they both gateways, gateway-router infrastructure doesn't suit to me) and I want to somehow "connect" wireless network interface from one router to wireless interface of another router so that internet traffic and dhcp would go through the second router(I have traffic inspector there). Is there are any ways how I could setup this? I've tried WDS but it didn't work well since the routers have different chipsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want one of them to be a gateway, but be able to create a single network. If so, set them up as a wireless bridge.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly(sorry for my English). I saw this manual but I can't afford to have one of them as a router, here in manual they say: "Go to setup/advanced routing and change the operating mode from "gateway" to router. Hit Apply."

Comment: I wish I could keep Firewall, Gateway mode and other settings enabled and somehow connect this virtual(yes, I forgot to mention that this wireless interface is virtual one, dd wrt allow to create virual AP's) AP's to second router.

Comment: If they are both a gateway I would recomend to make one a non gateway and the other gateway. That will allow you to disable the firewall on the wireless ethernet bridge. Which happens is what it is in this case.